# rtmp module stream do not , how to solve that?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I have some problem with configuring nginx+rtmp-module.
I need to stream a video from IP camera to web-site. I use MPEG-DASH.My server configuration is lower. Files .m4a, .m4v are creating and I also have stream.mpd file. But in browser it doen't work, inifinity loading. some logs from dash.js

```
Time: 0
dash.all.js:2:10794
Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
dash.all.js:2:10818
Index for time 0 is -1
dash.all.js:3:8722
Checking for stream end...
dash.all.js:3:8722
Live never ends! (TODO)
dash.all.js:3:8722
Stream finished? false
dash.all.js:3:8722
Got a request.
dash.all.js:3:8722
null
dash.all.js:3:8722
BufferController video setState to:READY
dash.all.js:3:8722
Working time is video time: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
BufferController.validate() video | state: READY
dash.all.js:3:8722
video Playback rate: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
video Working time: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
video Video time: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
Current video buffer length: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
BufferController video setState to:VALIDATING
dash.all.js:3:8722
ABR enabled? (true)
dash.all.js:3:8722
Check ABR rules.
dash.all.js:3:8722
Checking download ratio rule...
dash.all.js:3:8722
Total time: 0.009s
dash.all.js:3:8722
Download time: 0.009s
dash.all.js:3:8722
The ratios are NaN, bailing.
dash.all.js:3:8722
Checking insufficient buffer rule...
dash.all.js:3:8722
Not enough information for rule.
dash.all.js:3:8722
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
dash.all.js:3:8722
New quality of 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
video Playback quality: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
Populate video buffers.
dash.all.js:3:8722
Quality didn't change.
dash.all.js:3:8722
Loading the video fragment for time: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
Getting the request for time: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
Got segments.
dash.all.js:3:8722
Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
dash.all.js:3:8722
Got a list of segments, so dig deeper.
dash.all.js:3:8722
Couldn't figure out a time!
dash.all.js:2:10751
Time: 0
dash.all.js:2:10794
Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
dash.all.js:2:10818
Index for time 0 is -1
dash.all.js:3:8722
Checking for stream end...
dash.all.js:3:8722
Live never ends! (TODO)
dash.all.js:3:8722
Stream finished? false
dash.all.js:3:8722
Got a request.
dash.all.js:3:8722
null
dash.all.js:3:8722
BufferController video setState to:READY
dash.all.js:3:8722
Working time is video time: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
BufferController.validate() video | state: READY
dash.all.js:3:8722
video Playback rate: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
video Working time: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
video Video time: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
Current video buffer length: 0
dash.all.js:3:8722
BufferController video setState to:VALIDATING
dash.all.js:3:8722
ABR enabled? (true)
dash.all.js:3:8722
Check ABR rules.
dash.all.js:3:8722
Checking download ratio rule...
dash.all.js:3:8722
Total time: 0.009s
dash.all.js:3:8722
Download time: 0.009s
dash.all.js:3:8722
The ratios are NaN, bailing.
```

```
user some_user;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {
    live on;
    dash on;
    server {
        listen 1935;
        application cams {
        dash_path /cams;
    }
        exec_static ffmpeg -i
 rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.51/1/Streaming/Channels/1/ -c:v libx264 -q:v 31 -an -profile:v baseline -ar 44100
 -f flv rtmp://0.0.0.0/cams/stream;

    }
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root /;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

}
```

Can someone explain me why stream is not working and how to issue that?thanks

Comment: what does browser console say?

Comment: @BijayRegmi I wrote part of console log in the first code form